# Use Java Program As Start UP Script Linux (RHEL5) Giving Error?

Tags: java, linux, sh, daemon

hi i have created my jar file PingConsolApps.jar and i have run this jar file at terminal running fine now o want to add it as a service that would start up on boot so i have put my jar file in "/home" place and i have created file PingConsolApps in etc/init.d as following this site,

http://www.shayanderson.com/linux/ad...-on-bootup.htm

but i have edited it here,
Code:

```
#! /bin/sh 

case "$1" in 
      start) 
            cd /home/ 
            /usr/bin/java -jar PingConsolApps.jar & 
            ;; 
      stop) 
            killall -v java 
            ;; 
esac 
exit 0
```

i gave permission to it ,

Code:

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/PingConsolApps
```

and after it i execute,

Code:

```
chmod 777 /etc/init.d/PingConsolApps
```

i try to start its service

Code:

```
/etc/init.d/PingConsolApps start
```

it does not show any error but after it i check it using

Code:

```
service PingConsolApps status
```

it does not show any thing and do not give ant error i check it in running service,

Code:

```
service --status -all
```

i do not get it there also

when i try to stop it

Code:

```
/etc/init.d/PingConsolApps stop
```

it give error "java: no process killed"

if it run this service then my sql data base would be updates while it do not up date ???

what are the mistakes in this script help me out to get my goals i am new to linux and development to specially like creating this services

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

See: [http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:SysVInitScript#Initscript_template](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging%3aSysVInitScript#Initscript_template)

It is mandatory to have a line like:

```
#chkconfig 234 90 10
```

Comment: yes i have seen it but i am not getting how to get it ?? why tehy have not use this line the link i mentioned above

Comment: As root, run the command  "chkconfig --add <name>".
Where name is the name of your wrapper (containing the #chkconfig line).
Then run "chkconfig --list" and check if your service has been added.